# Button click open song file

Tags: wpf, button, click, playback

I'm a begginer in visual basic wpf apps, i just want to click on a button and it play the song.
My task is to put some alarm songs on this app just to give it to my mate and he chooses the best alarm song.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `System.Windows.Controls.MediaElement` to play music files.

http://vbcity.com/blogs/xtab/archive/2009/06/29/how-to-play-sounds-and-music-in-wpf.aspx